# An Exception occurs when writing to the xlsx document in iteration using apache poi 3.9

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

[image]Am trying to update the values in excel during iterations.
For example say value of Cell5 ,i'm trying to update it over iteration.
It worked fine for `.xls(HSSFWorkbook)`

But when trying to do the same with `XSSFWorkbook(.xlsx)`

But following exception occurs:

> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException

Referencing to previous post on this exception i tried to include this piece of code

```
        FileOutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Ash\\poi\\res.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);            
        out.close();
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("E:\\Ash\\poi\\res.xlsx"));
```

including exception is not occuring but,only one iteration data is getting updated in the excel,set of them are blank.

This is my code:
       public class poiTestxlsx {

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       String excelFilePath = "E:\\Ash\\poi\\poiread.xlsx";
          FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
          Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
          int rowCnt=firstSheet.getLastRowNum();

          for (int i = 1; i <=rowCnt ; i++) {
             Row r = firstSheet.getRow(i);        
              int res=i;
              Cell cell=null;
              if(cell==null){
                cell=r.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(res);
                }
            FileOutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(new   File("E:\\Ash\\poi\\res.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);            
            out.close();
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new           FileInputStream("E:\\Ash\\poi\\res.xlsx"));
         }
          System.out.println("done");
        }
      }
```

The same code worked for `HSSFWorkbook`, the result sheet had iterated values been updated.
Please let me know how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the saving part outside your for loop and you're all set :)

I took your code and altered it a bit, not much though. Just changed from sheet to to XSSFSheet and row to XSSFrow for consistancy. Then moved the saving part outside of for loop. looks like this.
   /**
   * The `ExcelTest` class
   */

public class ExcelTest{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\gotpist1\\Desktop\\SRBNOI.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    XSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowCnt = firstSheet.getLastRowNum();
    try{
        for(int i = 1; i <= rowCnt; i++){
            if(i == 3)
                break;
            XSSFRow r = firstSheet.getRow(i);
            int res = i;
            Cell cell = null;
            if(cell == null){
                cell = r.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue("f" + res);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\gotpist1\\Desktop\\SRBNOI.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println("done");
    }

}
```

}

[image: Output]

Comment: No problem! Glad i Could help :)

Comment: can we  not save their result in excel for each iteration separately?

Comment: Like in qtp the results gets saved after every iteration and we can find the data till successful iteration..... but in selenium I see only after completion of iteration the excel is getting updated ,it's updating at each iteration

Comment: Im not really understand what you're asking? Do you want to write one row, then save the file, then open it up again and write the second row?

Comment: Yes .. write one row save and then open write and save another row

Comment: Im guessing it is possible, but why? :)

Comment: I'm working on web application ,I input data for the appl via excel and after iteration I want the result to get update in the my sheet...by using this logic ..my result sheet gets updated only after the entire iteration is getting completed. If it fails by any chance the result sheet is not having the date updated for the successful cases as well

Comment: Ok, well, then you will have to open up a new inputstream and workbook for every iteration aswell. Because you close them when you use workbook.write(out); It will be quite slow though, but then it will do what you ask for. Then put outPutStream, write and close inside the for loop.

Comment: on doing that i gett org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException exception

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Will post the working code in an hour. In the meantime, try solving it by locating on which row the error occurs. :)

Comment: I have posted the new code in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: What I was asking is for suppose if u include a break if i=3 , the result sheet should have the data saved for values of i=1 andi=2

Comment: The code i posted does exactly that. Just tried it. Put a break if i=3. It then printed 1 in the 1 row on The fifth column and 2 on The 2 row in The fifth column. You need some values in your excel though.

Comment: Oh..I copied Ur code and tired..in row2 at 5th cell is saving 2 ,but row1 no value is present

Comment: The for loop starts at 1, the first column is 0. Try changing I = 1 to I = 0.

Comment: ha hb hc hd hf hg
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 
a4 b4 c4 d4 e4


this is my output when (i==3) break;  1st iteration value 1 is not getting saved

Comment: i have attached the output screenshot in the my question.

Comment: Add The code you are using now, something must be wrong.

Comment: Did you change The forloop?

Comment: on copy pasted ur code, only the last row has the iteration  value updated in the result sheet. 
and inserting if (i==3)break; is resulting with 2 saved the value in  the 2nd iteration .

But iteration 1 result is not getting saved .

Comment: Yes, but i told you to try and change the forloop in a comment higer up. Change the i = 1 to i = 0. I am using this code, and getting 
0
1
2
as output in column 5 when i added an if statment to check if the iteration is hitting 3.

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to acchive. If you want to start adding values on the second row, as i think you are, then i should  be 1. I will copy and paste the code one more time. And with the output that i get from using that code.

Comment: Come to think of it. A try/catch/finally would be much more efficient. Then you only need to put the saving part in the finally clause. That way, if anything breaks, it will store as many rows it had written before the crash.

Comment: I put the new Code  in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tired with Ur previous code..but still I didn't my difference... does the version of poi matters??

Comment: Did you try the code I just posted, with the try catch and it didn't work?

Comment: ThankQ so much this code is working as excepted :) super cool :)